# Div column is not aligned in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create Tree Table control using HTML and Bootstrap. Below is the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/g3d5mf83/2/

```
 <body>
  <h2>Balance Groups</h2>
  <br>

<div class="container">
    <div class="ad-tree-browser-container tree-bordered">
      <div data-level="0" class="tree-view">
        <div class="tree">
          <div>
            <div class="tree-level tree-header-level border">
              <div class="content">
                 <div class="content-holder">
                    <div class="node-content ad-user-select-none">
                      <div>
                         <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">Lables</div>
                         <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">Value Balance</div>
                         <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">Value Balance (EUR)</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
             </div>

             <div class="tree-level tree-top-level border">
               <div class="content" style="padding-left: 15px;">
                 <div class="content-holder">
                  <div class="toggle">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="node-content">
                    <div class="small-gutter">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                            AED
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
                            274,648.02
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
                            53,446.47
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                </div>
               </div>
               <div>
                  <div class="tree-level tree-sub-level">
                    <div class="content" style="padding-left: 30px;">
                      <div class="content-holder">
                       <div class="toggle">
                         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
                       </div>
                       <div class="node-content">
                         <div class="small-gutter">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                                CITI
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
                                274,648.02
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
                                53,446.47
                            </div>
                         </div> 
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Here the problem is that **Value Balance** column is not getting aligned.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: replace `col-sm-` with `col-xs-`

Comment: Still getting the same problem.

Comment: Updated Your fiddle. please check it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g3d5mf83/5/

Comment: Still _Value Balance_ column is not aligned as _Value Balance (EUR)_ column.